# Breaking loop when users selects N

Tags: c, loops

I have the program below, that lets the users select foods to buy in a loop. Now I need a way to break the loop when the user is done selecting foods. When the user enters `Y` for yes the program should ask for the next food. 
If the user enter `N` for no the program should break the loop and print out the total price for all the food chosen.

```
p("[1] Spinach\n");
    p("[2] Romaine\n");
    p("[3] Mustard\n");
    p("[4] Carrots\n");
    p("[5] Potato\n");
    p("[6] Yam\n");
    p("[7] Asparagus\n");
    p("[8] Brocolli\n");
    p("[9] Melon\n");
    p("[10] Strawberry\n");

    do{
    p("Pick food: ");
    s("%d",&choice);
    if(choice == 1){
        p("\n\nHow many grams of Spinach? ");
        s("%f",&spinach);
        spinachT+=spinach*spinachP;
        p("\nPrice: P %.2f",spinachT);

        p("Enter again?");
        s("%s", &yn);
        if(strcmp(yn, "y")==0){
            ??? enter again new food
        }else{
            ??? stop print price
        }
        }
    }while(choice == 11);
}
```

Comment: Don't shorten standard function names, that meks your code hard to understand for others, and that will include yourself in a few months time.

Comment: p for printf, s for scanf. sorry by the way my bad..

Comment: Then you might want to learn about the `break` and `continue` statements.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: The program will prompt all the 10 choices
In these exam we will use foods
after the user choses one of the food
the program will ask how many grams  of the chosen food 
Then after the user  enters the amount of grams
The program will print the price of the chosen option 
Then the program will ask if the user would like to ask another food from the list 
If the user enters Yes then then cycle will repeat asking the food and the grams, 
If no, the program will print all the foods and grams chosen and the price @MartinZabel

Comment: Isn't there a missing '{'

Comment: Think about this: Do you really want to "break out" of an if-statement? Or do you want to break out of the do-while statement? (I will not solve this homework.)

Comment: i just want to break out of the if statement then go do the do-statement again. @MartinZabel fyi this is not a homework, its a project. hehe.

Comment: what do you mean @ch3rub7 i mean can you please give me an example?

Comment: @Alphang, first of all you should read what people are saying here. The answer to the questions is already presented in one of the comments. Read them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the loop using `break ;` or move to the first line of the loop with `continue ;`